# How to compare two objects and determine their equality score

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

The problem is to compare two objects (instance of same class having 5 String field values each) and determine an integer score based on their relative equality.

5 Strings combined make a name for any item for Example **Apple iPhone 5s Gold 16GB**

Please suggest me some concepts which i can look into to develop the solution of the mentioned problem.

Comment: What are you talking about? What is 'address(Home Address) match score' supposed to be?

Comment: I'm with @ArtjomB. - where is this coming form? Your basic issue is to decide which part of the string is which variable in the class. Once that is done, you need a `distance` function for each variable (different street VS different country). Then decide on an accumulative function for the whole class.

Comment: You'll need to specify how the string relate and what kind of relationship the strings have to each other. Without that information this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is actually about string similarity, the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and its close relative, the [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), provide measures for the so-called edit distance of strings. One possibility to implement an aggregated measure of similarity would be to compare the corresponding members and use the sum of their edit distances.

Comment: I think the idea here is not to do with `Levenshtein distance` but with distances between variables. `d(211,111) > d(112,111)` I think

Comment: Might be, but the OP mentions 5 instance variables of type string.

Comment: True, but before the edit, s/he was talking about a given address in a class with 5 variables (country, city. etc.) and wanted to measure the distance. The address was given in a single string.